# Closing WPF dialog box from contained UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls

Hi I have a WPF application with various UserControls that contain key functionality. I want to be able to show say a FileManager UserControl in a tab on the main application, or have a dialog pop up when required, that contains the same UserControl.

It seemed like a good idea to create a modal Window and set its `Content` to the `FileManager` Usercontrol. But when I am finished with it, I am not sure how to close the containing Window, using a button on the UserControl. Is there an elegant way of doing this without having to store a reference to the Window in the UserControl?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is closing a window something that is integral to the functionality of the control in all the contexts where the control is hosted?  E.g Does closing a window apply to the case where the control is hosted in a tab of the main app?

If not then you might be better off separating window closing code out of the UserControl in into the window/dialog that is hosting it - using events or whatever to tie the two together.

Comment: Thanks, that made me think. You're right, putting the close button in the usercontrol makes no sense if it is hosted in a non closing dialog. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Create an `Event` which is called when the respective button on the user control is clicked. That way, the containing control can react to the event in the appropriate manner. For example, a dialog could just close itself.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer.

Comment: @DaveClemmer: why didn't you change the second occurrence of *Event* as well? And why did you change the first one?

Comment: @Thorsten, I certainly could have highlighted both occurrences, the first occurrence seemed to me to be more of a coding action (hence the highlighting) and the second more of a description in a natural sentence.  You can edit as you wish. :-)